# How to have `auto form fill` works with hidden form fields?

Tags: firefox-extensions, lastpass, auto-form-fill

Currently I'm using Firefox addon LastPass to have my PHP web application form quickly tested.

My issue is that I cannot auto-fill the hidden field whose value is entered via a popup window.

How can I auto-fill it too?

Nam

ps
Trying to edit the saved form-fill entry I cannot enter the hidden fields as below shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you save the site and the "edit" the entry, look for a link in the lower right area of the edit box called "Edit Form Fields".  The value may be there.

If it's not, then you may need to recreate the entry.  After you fill in all of the data, but before you hit "Submit" or "Login" or whatever it is, go to the LastPass menu and select "Save All Entered Data".

One of those two should work for you.

Comment: 1) `The value may be there` - no it is not 2) As I said, `hidden field` just NOT showed up in LastPass save entry Joe

Answer (score 0):

[untested] Before saving the form data I'd use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to change the hidden form filed to text (`<input type="text" ... />`). Since the input's id or name stays the same I suppose LP will fill it.